# Matrix reciprocal positive $5\times 5$, $6\times 6$ or bigger

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have $n\times n$ matrix $A$ having only positive elements and satisfying the property $a_{ij}=\dfrac{1}{a_{ji}}$ (a matrix satisfying this property is called a reciprocal matrix).

If its largest eigenvalue $λ_{max}$ is equal to $n$, then the matrix $A$ satisfies the property (consistency property) $a_{ij}a_{jk}=a_{ik}$ where $i,j,k=1,2,...,n$.

---

I already found an example of $5\times 5$ reciprocal matrix  to show this condition:

\begin{bmatrix}1&1/2&1&1&1/4\\2&1&2&2&1/2\\1&1/2&1&1&1/4\\1&1/2&1&1&1/4\\4&2&4&4&1\end{bmatrix}

It has simple characteristic equation $λ^5-5λ^4=0$, so the eigenvalues of matrix $A$ are $λ=0$ and $λ=5$ and it's shown that $λ_{max}=n=5$.

Is there anyone can help me to give another positive reciprocal matrix example  that has simple characteristic equation and integer number as its eigenvalues ($5\times 5$ or $6\times 6$ or bigger size matrix)?